# Italy's microdata sources

Tags: data-request, demographics, italy

Italy has a huge problem with individual-level data. [ISTAT](https://www.istat.it/en/) provides some data but on specific topics and rarely they are year-to-year data. [INPS](https://www.inps.it) has some other data but only regarding labor market.

If one wants to do economic/social research about Italy   and needs individual-level data, where he should look? Which are the best sources of microdata about Italy? I am thinking about data on education, health, crime, ...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if a portal is useful, if it doesn't have the right data, but here's the Italy Open Data Portal

https://www.dati.gov.it/

with 27k+ datasets:

https://www.dati.gov.it/search/type/dataset

from the Agency for Digital Italy: https://www.agid.gov.it/